# How to do a zpl batch printing

Tags: zpl

I am able to print the labels by sending zpl commands to the printer.
Now how to do a batch printing of zpl labels programatically.
suppose if have multiple labels to be printed in a single printjob.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You want to print it programmatically using ZPL or do you use Another language (which I assume) in the application triggering the prints?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to simply send all the labels together as a single ZPL command string.

Just do an `^XZ` command to end the current label
and then `^XA` to start the next one.

Comment: That's good for readability, but all the printers I've dealt with _do not_ require any new line characters.

Answer (score 2):

If the batch of labels are all identical, you can just add the `^PQ` command before the `^XZ`. The `^PQ` command is used to have a single label printed multiple times, so adding `^PQ50` would make the label print 50 times.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that will generate a batch of 500 labels.  It includes an increment number within a barcode which is also displayed as text.

```
^XA
^FO250,40^A0N,70,70^FDLPN^FS
^FO30,120^A0N,50,50
^BCN,100,N,N,N
^FD1000001^SFddddddd^FS
^FO200,300^A0N,50,50
^FD1000001^SFddddddd^FS
^PQ500
^XZ
```